# Error 28: Expression must have a constant value

Tags: c++, struct, constants, typedef, keil

I have a section of c++ code in keil uvision5 that is getting error 28: expression must have a constant value.  I am trying to figure out how to fix it.

this is the line (inside of a function) that it is happening on:

```
osPoolDef_t pool_def = { queue_def->queue_sz,  queue_def->item_sz};
```

it does not like the variables queue_sz or item_sz.

here is the definition of osPoolDef_t:

```
typedef const struct os_pool_def  {
  uint32_t                 pool_sz;    /*  number of items (elements) in the pool */
  uint32_t                 item_sz;    /*  size of an item */
  void                     *pool;      /*  pointer to memory for pool */
} osPoolDef_t;
```

and queue_def is a pointer to osMailQDef_t shown below:

```
typedef const struct os_mailQ_def  {
  uint32_t                queue_sz;    /*  number of elements in the queue */
  uint32_t                 item_sz;    /*  size of an item */
  struct os_mailQ_cb **cb;
} osMailQDef_t;
```

hopefully that is enough information.

It seems that the problem is that I am not using c99 anymore, but the code worked fine for that file when I used c99.  Is there a way to force the compilation of just that file to be done with c99?

Comment: Are you trying to do that initialization outside a function?

Comment: in C you must have a constant value here. But not in C++. Are you sure you are using a C++ compiler?

Comment: @MattMcNabb it is a c file but I am using a c++ compiler. When I compiled using c99 it worked but my main file is c++ so I am not using c99 anymore.

Comment: perhaps your compiler decides to create .c files as C

Comment: Try to include the c file within a cpp file.

Comment: So apparently `{ queue_def->queue_sz,  queue_def->item_sz}` is not a constant expression and thus can't be used for static initialization. @MattMcNabb _'But not in C++'_ Depends on where this line is actually placed.

Comment: I changed it to a cpp file and that just created a bunch of other problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force the armcc compiler to use C99 with the --c99 option.