# Why do I get #28 expression must be a constant value while initializing struct in C?

Tags: c, struct, constants

I'm trying to initialize a `struct` with values passed as function arguments, as follows:

```
struct my add(uint16_t x, uint16_t y, const char *text, uint8_t b, uint8_t c)
{
    struct my M =
    { x, y, NULL, NULL, text, b, NULL, NULL, c, NULL, NULL};
    array[count] = my;
    count++;

}
```

However, on the line with `struct` initialization, I get:

```
#28 expression must have a constant value
```

How else do I achieve it, without getting this error?

Comment: You already have a worst problem, `widgets` and `widget_count` are global, which means there might be some other design problems. Why don't you just make a struct containing a list of `struct widget` objects or an array containing the array size? and then write some accessor functions to initialize the struct correctly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error 28: Expression must have a constant value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24528084/error-28-expression-must-have-a-constant-value)

Comment: array containing the array size - could you explain? Right now I have `struct widget widgets[50]`

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: @MichałSzydłowski probably, that could work, still your initialization is realy ugly. You can use `memset()`.

Comment: I'm using ARM compiler, it's an embedded project

Comment: Why do you initialise integers with the `NULL`-pointer value?

Comment: @alk right, didn't notice that because that initialization is hard to look at ... now my `memset()` suggestion makes more sense.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error "initializer element is not constant" when trying to initialize variable with const](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025050/error-initializer-element-is-not-constant-when-trying-to-initialize-variable-w)

Comment: Dubplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025050/error-initializer-element-is-not-constant-when-trying-to-initialize-variable-w

Comment: Please post `struct my` definition.

Comment: The problem is solved, @iharob 's answer turned out to work nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important problem I see is that you are assigning the `text` pointer to your struct's `text` pointer, which is most likely wrong since the `text` field is not `const`.

Removing the `const` from the parameter could also be wrong, adding it to the `struct` field could be Ok if you ensure that the contents pointed to by this pointer will remain valid through out the life of the struct instance.

What you are trying to do is a lot cleaner if you just `memset(&widget, 0, sizeof(widget))`<sup>1</sup> and then initialize each field like this

```
struct widget instance;
memset(&instance, 0, sizeof(instance));

instance.x    = x;
instance.y    = y;
instance.text = malloc(1 + text_size);
if (instance.text != NULL)
    strcpy(instance.text, text);
instance.text_size = text_size;
instance.text_font = text_font;
```

and then the

```
widgets[widget_count++] = instance;
```

part, should not go in that function, that function should just

```
return instance;
```

wherever you allocated the `widgets` array manipulate both the array and the `widget_count` variable, don't make them global just to be able to access them from another function, if you must access them from another function pass them as parameters, if you have to modify `widget_count` in another function pass it's address as a paramter.

But the way you have it, the context is not clear, so you might end up doing very bad things when the code gets more complex.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>You need to include `string.h` in order to use `memset()` and `strcpy()`</sub>

Comment: Maybe, if `text` the passed pointer, is not a static literal string allocated in the stack frame of a function that will return and then the data will be deallocated leading to Undefined Behavior, you should also make the `text` field `const` and be sure that the described probelm will not happen, with the code posted in your question it's not possible to tell you if it's ok to just assign the pointer, it could be ... you need to learn about poitners I think.

Comment: But I ask again - HOW can I modify a field that is `const`?

Comment: Oh, I see ... you don't want to modify it, you will assign to it, it's not the same, the contents are `const` the pointer is not in this `const char *pointer;`  you can make `pointer` point wherever you want, but you cant alter the pointed to content. This `const char *const pointer;` makes both `const`, the pointer and the pointed to data. If you want to alter the pointee, then you **must** copy the data.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the compiler complains that you are try to initialise a non-`const` member of a `struct` (`char *text`)  with a `const` value (`const char *text`) as being passed in.

To get around this either remove the `const` from the argument's definition or define the `struct`'s member to be `const`.

Comment: Yes, but the member cannot be constant, how could I modify it then?

Comment: @MichałSzydłowski you need to make a copy of it, like my answer suggests.